# How to upload files from my site with php to my personal onedrive account?

Tags: php, onedrive

I would like to allow my users to upload files from an html / php form from my site to my personal onedrive account. Then get the sharing links from these files.

I looked at **microsoft.com and stackoverflow**, but I do not understand how to upload the file directly into my account and not the user's.
Thank you very much for helping me find the trick or the piece of code to make it happen!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/upload?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: Looks like there's an API available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started  "I do not understand" isn't really a question we can explicitly and concretely answer.  You are encouraged to start with the documentation and make an attempt.  It looks like registering your app and authorizing the operation is the main issue, after that you would upload to a simple REST endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content

Comment: OK, thanks. I tried with the Microsoft API but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flysystem. https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/usage/filesystem-api/

Then all your storage stuff uses a really easy to use similar API. Then just add the onedrive adapter, and you can call it the same way you call any of the others :-)

https://packagist.org/packages/nicolasbeauvais/flysystem-onedrive

Comment: Is this package still working? It's marked as unmaintained.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried it and I think I can get by with this method :-)